# React Table - User COntrolled Header background Color

Tags: css, reactjs, react-component

I have a re-useable table component that I am styling with vanilla CSS. I have six possible colors that I would like users to be able to pick from to change the table header background color if wanted. Ideally, this color choice should be a prop on the component, but I'm not sure how to do this.

In my CSS file I have the color variables defined:

```
th {
 --deq-primary: #0080b7;
  --daq-primary: #1ab7da;
  --ddw-primary: #147995;
  --dwq-primary: #034a64;
  --derr-primary: #05a68b;
  --dwmrc-primary: #f26322;
}

th {
  background-color: var(--deq-primary);
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
}
```

Is it possible to set a prop on my table to accept one of these values so that the header background color can be changes within the component?

Something like

```
<MyTable headerColor="ddw-primary" />
```

the the header color would change to the ddw-primary color

**UPDATE**
I was able to implement Hugo Elhaj-Lahsen suggestion. The variable name is being passed as a string and I updated the example he provided to account for the `--` that is required in the variable name. So the final style tag in the code looks like

```
return <table style={{backgroundColor: `var(--${headerColor})` }}>
  {// ...}
</table>


....
>
```

In the component I'm passing the var name as a string:

```
<MyTable
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        headerColor="my-color-variable-name"
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible React solution without libs would be to pass the CSS variable name as props, and **reference it in the style of your component**. Suppose we have:

```
<MyTable headerColor="ddw-primary" />
```

and your CSS variables defined in the `MyTable` component. Assuming you style via the `style=` property, you can do:

```
return <table style={{backgroundColor: `var(${headerColor})` }}>
  {// ...}
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked and I've added it to the original post so others can see my final code